# Trying to create an index of attempt ID within a user ID based on date and Category

Tags: r

I have a file with a couple of millions of rows for which I want to create an index sequence column (1 to n attempts) for each users' attempt, within the attempted category and ordered by date. I have a `userID`, `attemptID`, `attemptCat` (attempt category) and an `attempt_date` field.

```
UserID <- c("AYY4","AYY4","AYY4","AYY4","AYY5","AYY5","AYY5","AYY6","AYY6","AYY6","AYY6","AYY6")

AttemptID <- c("5437621B","5437685F","543776H","5437945S","58380Y1A","58380Y4D","58380Y6G","5Y675A-BWM","5Y675A-BWM","6266YA-GBW","5Y675A-BWM","6266YA-GBW")

AttemptCat <- c(1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)

AttemptDate <- c("17/12/2019","18/12/2019","19/12/2019","20/12/2019","21/12/2019","22/12/2019","23/12/2019","24/12/2019","25/12/2019","26/12/2019","27/12/2019","28/12/2019")

MYData <- data.frame(UserID, AttemptID, AttemptCat, AttemptDate)
```

I would like to create an index sequence that represents the attempt number per category ordered by date. So for this example, the index would come out like this:

```
AttemptIndex <- c(1,2,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,3)
```

Would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: Thank you zx8754 :) - Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Using *data.table*, as data is in millions, it might be more efficient, convert date column to date class, group by user and attempt category, then add row number - *ix*:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table 
setDT(MYData)

MYData[, AttemptDate := as.Date(AttemptDate, "%d/%m/%Y") ]
MYData[ order(AttemptDate), ix := seq_along(.I), by = .(UserID, AttemptCat)]

# compare to expected output
all(MYData$ix == AttemptIndex)
# [1] TRUE
```